# Power Supply (220vac to 5v dc/2A)

Tags: power-supply

I'm designing a power supply for a smart switch project which requires a 5v dc/2A supply for usb charger and 12V dc for relay operation. is there any way i could do that? my input is 220ac, which will be rectified to 310(approx) dc. any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There can only be one suggestion for this: **DON'T**. Designing mains supplies is a job for a **specialist**. The fact that you do not know more than getting to 310 V DC means you are not such a specialist. Also there are loads of ready made safe and even cheap power adapters which will fit your 5V, 2A requirement. So don't design your own, it is pointless and dangerous. Buy a ready made one.

Comment: well i know some electronics(electronics engineer) and i'm aware of the danger. but i'm facings troubles with this problem as i want my circuit to be small and efficient.

Comment: I have been an EE for 23 years and know my MOV from creeping distance and isolation slots yet even I would **buy** that power supply instead of designing my own. Even I will be **unable** to design a cheaper, smaller and more efficient adapter than those that are available already. So what makes you think that **you** can do better than me and all other specialists ?

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't want to offend you or any other specialist. Its just that i'm new. and i think its no harm trying new things and asking for suggestions.

Comment: No one is offended, no worries. Just explaining you like it is. Trying new things is always good but there are many **other** new things you can try and which will give you less frustration. Just for educational purposes, dismantle a few unused/broken supplies, reverse engineer them, figure out how they work. Learn why things are done like they are. Then whenever you need to design a supply which cannot be bought, then at least you know how they work.

Comment: @AitezazAhsan Bimpelrekkie advice is good, designing is power supply for standard output is like reinventing the wheel. I think you can even find smaller form factor designs.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to see someone else take a supply to bits and give comments on the design go here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiPG9SSI8xY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to use external AC/DC adaptor and connects to your project. It has many benefits.
(1) AC/DC has CE marking for both EMI and safety so you do not need to worry on that. It expensive to conducts CE certification. 
(2) Protects yourself from lawyer who may raise legal cases under poorly designed  AC/DC build in project.
(3) Many more benefits if you think about it more.

You need to implement sufficient EMI filtering and protection on your project from external 5V 2A PSU which is quite easy.

Good lucks

Comment: *It expensive to conducts CE certification.* True for other certifications but not CE. CE is just a document and you just "declare" that you're compliant. You could get sued though if that was untrue. Also see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0uvS80YIGU

Comment: And what you do to prove it compliant? that the expensive part. As I understood it must be performed by the competent 3rd party. I struggle to find self-declaration and certification would legally be a workable solution. China has abused the CE quite a lot.

Comment: *And what you do to prove it compliant?* Have an independent party test your product against the document. Have you even watched that video ? Why does China abuse the CE logo ? Because they can, there are almost no repercussions when using it "illegally" so they do. You're thinking of some institute enforcing the CE certification, well the truth is almost no-one cares until there's a problem with a product and the manufacturer gets sues for illegally using CE. I don't think that happens a lot because often the manufacturer is in China.

Comment: Right on! @Bimpelrekkie  I recall a ski resort in USA that used batteries on   lifts (DC-UPS) with 200 Amp spike pulse chargers and the emissions triggered the g sensors in cars nearby and deployed air bags from RF resonance in the car tuned to the burp charger used for desulfenation.